# StreamType deprecated. How to get the stream type?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to implement a PlaySound() method that should play a default Notification sound. It does work perfectly. Here's the code:

```
    public void PlaySound()
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        var notification = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
        mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(Application.Context, notification);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(Application.Context, notification);
        mediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType(r.StreamType);
        mediaPlayer.Prepare();
        mediaPlayer.Start();
    }
```

The compiler however tells me that r.StreamType is deprecated. I've looked at various locations but can't find the 'new' way to get the StreamType. Who does know?

Answer (score 3):

API 21 added `MediaPlayer.SetAudioAttributes` to replace `mediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType`, so you can do a runtime check to determine which API methods to use:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    var attribs = new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetFlags(AudioFlags.None).SetLegacyStreamType(Stream.Ring).Build();
    mediaPlayer.SetAudioAttributes(attribs);
}
else
{
    mediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType(r.StreamType);
}
```

Comment: would you please add some explanation about AudioFlags.None, Stream.Ring?

Comment: @TamimProduction The AudioAttributes docs go through all the different flags: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html

Comment: hello, can you please help me with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210872/mediaplayer-stream-alarm-not-working-properly