# MediaPlayer - setAudioAttributes not working properly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-alarms

I'm trying to create an alarm, everything is working fine but the stream type is always media even tho I use `STREAM_ALARM`, since `setStreamType` is deprecated, I'm using `setAudioAttributes` instead but it doesn't seem to work.
here's my code :

```
class AlarmRingtoneManager(val context: Context) {

    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

    fun start() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
           .apply {
              setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build())
              isLooping = true
              start()
           }
    }

    fun stop() {
      mediaPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: I run your code and works without problems

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the `MediaPlayer` using the method `MediaPlayer.create()`, and it is not possible to change the `AudioAttributes` later if you do it like that.

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%2520int)):

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. **On
>   success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be
>   called again.**
>
> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the
>   resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.
>
> **Note that since prepare() is called automatically in this method, you
>   cannot change the audio session ID (see setAudioSessionId(int)) or
>   audio attributes (see
>   setAudioAttributes(android.media.AudioAttributes) of the new
>   MediaPlayer.**

Instead of using `create()`, just instantiate the `MediaPlayer` using the default constructor `new MediaPlayer();`. Then, set the source with the method `setDataSource()` and set the rest of the AudioAttributes as you were doing before.

I don't know about Kotlin, but in Java it would look something like this:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build());
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version

```
    val uri = Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI ?: Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI
    uri?.let {
        val player = MediaPlayer()
        player.setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build()
        )
        //player.reset() //uncomment this line if you use local variable of MediaPlayer
        player.setDataSource(this@AlarmActivity, it)
        player.prepare()
        player.start()
    }
```